# facebook share link count

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter, count, share

Is there any way to get number of users share some link on facebook and twitter

example: how many times some link was shared to facebook and twitter to calculate popularity of some content

Are there some api ?

Comment: I need this becouse i build an deal aggregator and I think that formula: number of facebook share * number of twitter share * yelp rating to calculate the most popular deals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For facebook: http://graph.facebook.com/http://google.com and for twitter you can hack counter of the tweet button but it's not an official API.

Comment: cool, thannks. i will sum the facebook shares,likes and comment to get some rating... but what i need to do for twitter?

Comment: Use a tool likes Charles Proxy or Chrome Web Inspector for sniffing the call made by the tweet button to twitter api. You can make the same.